# Strongly typed dataset (.xsd) error VS Community Edition 15.8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, dataset

I updated my VS Community Edition to 15.8.1 and after that I got this error when I tried to edit my sql inside strongly typed dataset.

> ```
> Configure TableAdapter failed
>
> Unable to find connection 'my_connection' for object 'Web.config'.
> The connection string could not be found in application settings, 
> or the data provider associated with the connection string 
> could not be loaded."
> ```

Comment: FWIW, there are several mentioned issues on the VS Developer Community related to the VS 15.8.x problems with Table Adapters and their connection strings. Most important one is ["Table Adapter not using connection strings in web.config"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/328831/visual-studio-2017-table-adapter-not-using-connect.html), to which I highly suggest everyone encountering this please upvote it.

Comment: Hey guys I tried the last version of VS Community Edition and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue this morning. What worked was to open the .xsd in text view, then change every instance of "(Web.config)" to "(Settings)" and set the "AppSettingsObjectName" value(s) to "Settings" as well.

Comment: I think thats the only way. For now  I downgraded my VS. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick for me. Still requiring a downgrade as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by first creating a "new" connection - that is I recreated the connection under a different name.

Then I went into the source code of the dataset object to see the results and compared it to the connection string that was there initially.

For me, the result was changing the code in the Source code of the dataset object

From: `AppSettingsObjectName="Web.config"`

To: `AppSettingsObjectName="MySettings"`

And also every ConnectionRef in the source of the dataset object

From: `ConnectionRef="ConnectionString (Web.config)"`

To: `ConnectionRef="BHBrowserConnectionString (MySettings)"`